# Create a Javascript API Class with multiple base urls

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, prototype

My backend includes multiple microservices, each with its own base url. At the moment I have the `user` and the `metadata` services, but this could expand in the future.

I have a React app and I'm trying to create an API wrapper class to call when I need to modify something. My first approach was to create multiple api instances for each service and import as needed:

```
import userApi from '../userApi'
import metadataApi from '../metadataApi'

userApi.getUser(user_id)
metadataApi.getCollections()
```

But I'd like to use a different approach that wouldn't require keeping note where each entity is located in order to use it, like so:

```
import API from '../api'

API.getUser(user_id)
API.getCollections()
API.deleteUser(user_id)
```

But I'm not sure how I can achive this without bloating up the API class. Can I import an array of methods inside it and just attach them to the class prototype before exporting?

I want to find a suitable structure to better separate each entity and make it easier to build and modify it in the future.

Comment: `base` definition: a conceptual structure or entity on which something draws or depends.
Therfor, you should not have one **base** for multiple entities.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, separating your API classes into separate files / modules is fine.  It feels like a bit of an overhead when the app is small, but as it grows, it helps keeps things organised.

You have already indicated that your backend API's are structured into microservices, why not keep them separate entities in the front end too?  It will be easier to manage your API classes when / if you ever come to start hitting different endpoints.

I have though, in the past, created a base class that each of those API classes may inherit from, where I can set up common logic, such as request headers etc, if you want to get some reuse that way.

I have even went a step further again which would create another level of abstraction that handles how the integration is happening, i.e. via HTTP, where I would declare which HTTP client to use for example.  That way, if I ever change the HTTP client, I only change it in one place

That kind of structure looked like ->

`_ServiceProxy.js`

Common functions such as GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
HTTP client defined here
High level error handling defined here

`_someBaseAPI.js`

An an abstract client that would define how to interact with a set of common microservices, e.g. Auth logic etc

`UserAPI.js`

A concrete / static class, only interested in how to handle requests / responses to do with Users

Comment: I second this approach. Seems like your architecture would benefit from being the same approach both front and back. Also, extending services using 'common' functionality ensures you keep core stuff within one place.  

Another idea would also to write these 'services' or modules in plain JS/TS and import them into your React lifecycle. Therefore you can port them to any other JS framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can define and export a separate component in which all api files will imported and use individual api in its functions, then you will be able to use its function for specific api.